Fabric capacity exceeded error in powerbi desktop when connecting to SQL server
Getting an error I've never seen before when trying to refresh a report which uses SQL server connector to connect to a fabric lakehouse.

The initial connection was fine and the first manual refresh has also worked. The second refresh few days later failed and since then I've been "trying again later" for a week with no luck. I've also asked my colleague to check and the same error prevented his refresh as well.
We have a Fabric trial.
From what I understand, the ideal connection would be through "Lakehouse" connector, but I wanted to quickly combine multiple sources in powerbi desktop before developing a semantic model in a lakehouse. The SQL endpoint connection seemed like a valid option. Other reports using direct lake have no issues. No other errors with any other artifacts related to compute capacity.
Does anyone have an idea how to deal with the problem expect for opting for the lakehouse connector?

You need to Monitor your Capacity and see what is using all the available capacity.
Fabric capacities never charge you more than you sign up to pay, but the flip side is that if you use all the available capacity, eventually it will stop accepting new requests.
